# Look up a value that may be formatted as text or a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've inherited a number of very old workbooks and they're a rats nest of links and lookups. I'm tidying them up and trying to get some structure into the sheets. One issue I'm continually running into is format mismatch. I'm using this formula currently which works for what I need:

```
=ifna(vlookup(A1&"",data!$a$1:$b$2000,2,0),vlookup(value(A1),data!$a$1:$b$2000,2,0))
```

But I'd like something tidier if it existed.

Is there an easier way to search text as numbers and numbers as text without changing the source data?

Comment: The only other option would be Array type formula which would be slower.

Comment: I did consider that too. It's also more complex.

Answer (score 2):

To search text as numbers, use =NUMBERVALUE().  That will convert numbers saved as text into a number and it won't have any effect on numbers saved as numbers.  If a cell contains letters, it'll return a #VALUE! error.

[image]

To convert numbers stored as text into numbers, you can also use a double negative like this.  Two negatives make a positive, but it also converts text like '1000 into a number like 1000.

```
=--B3
```

To search numbers as text, use =TEXT().  That will convert numbers to text.  Check the help menu for the options.

[image]

You can use those in formulas so that your lookups won't get confused by the mismatch.  For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(B3),B:B,1,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(B3,"#"),B:B,1,FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a formula that simplifies the ifna() and double vlookup() formula I'm using above. I use a similar method to test both formats. The shorthand concatenate (&) and blank space converts the cell to text. value() achieves the same as numbervalue() in what I need, but numbervalue() adds further arguments if required. I don't use absolute values as I'm unsure if the is a negative value in the data set.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I'm with you now, and I'll contemplate on it a little.

Comment: And for what it's worth, that double negative won't give you an absolute value.  If you start with a negative, it's effectively a triple negative so you still end up with a negative.

Comment: Good point! I missed that....

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=VLOOKUP(  TEXT(C1,"@"),  TEXT($A$1:$B$2000,"@"),  2,  FALSE)
```

You can take care of things for your range with a simple approach:  use `TEXT()` for both the lookup value AND for the lookup range.

I do not find any of Excel's frequent string length limitations to affect the use of `TEXT()` even using a lookup column of 108,000 cells. The usual max, WHEN limited, for strings Excel makes inside a formula is a MAXIMUM of 32,767 characters or so, and is often vastly lower. So if it will build an internal string for the formula that is a minimum of 108,000 characters (and my data is more than one character per cell so was much longer) it definitely exceeds any such limit I've ever seen or heard of so `VLOOKUP()` must not be a function limited that way. So `TEXT()` should always be fine.

It might seem that you could use `VALUE()` instead, but it fails if any material in the entire lookup range is non-numeric. So... not helpful.

So, a simple formula and no "consider this, consider that." No errors. No concerns.

A note for extending the use of this:  if you had a more complicated situation, one in which a value could appear both ways (as a numeric character formatted as a number in one cell, and as one formatted as text in another — so BOTH 6 and "6" occur), you cannot use this as it removes that distinction and would return a result from whichever of those came first. **It does this use case, but extending it to more complicated ones would require careful consideration.**

Comment: Thanks Jeorje, unfortunately this doesn't satisfy my use case as all returned values would be in text, not their original format.